# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'float32'

Tags: python-2.7, pytorch, torchtext

I am trying to use [OpenNMT-py](https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py) with python 2.7. OpenNMT-py requires `torchtext`, so I installed it but now when I am running my program, I am getting the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/StackPointerParser.py", line 23, in <module>
    from neuronlp2.io import get_logger, conllx_stacked_data
  File "./neuronlp2/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "./neuronlp2/models/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .parsing import *
  File "./neuronlp2/models/parsing.py", line 15, in <module>
    from onmt.modules import LayerNorm, Transformer
  File "/home/wasiahmad/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/onmt/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import onmt.io
  File "/home/wasiahmad/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/onmt/io/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from onmt.io.IO import collect_feature_vocabs, make_features, \
  File "/home/wasiahmad/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/onmt/io/IO.py", line 8, in <module>
    import torchtext.data
  File "/home/wasiahmad/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torchtext/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import data
  File "/home/wasiahmad/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torchtext/data/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .field import RawField, Field, ReversibleField, SubwordField, NestedField, LabelField
  File "/home/wasiahmad/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torchtext/data/field.py", line 61, in <module>
    class Field(RawField):
  File "/home/wasiahmad/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torchtext/data/field.py", line 115, in Field
    torch.float32: float,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'float32'
```

I tried to look for a solution to resolve this issue but couldn't find any. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey, did you actually solve the problem? If you found a solution it would be great if you could share it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more a guess, as you have not given information about your version. But it seems to me that your `torchtext` version is not compatible with your `PyTorch` version.

Probably when you installed `torchtext` you got the newer version already made for `PyTorch 0.4.0`. But your `PyTorch` version installed is still older than `0.4.0` (version `0.3.1` or so).

If that is the case you have two options. Downgrading torchtext to a version compatible to yours (probably the version before). Or upgrading `PyTorch` to version `0.4.0`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

What's your pytorch version? As per the readme of the github repo of [torchtext](https://github.com/pytorch/text/) :

> For PyTorch versions before 0.4.0, please use pip install torchtext==0.2.3.

I was facing this exact problem with pytorch 0.3.1 and torchtext 0.3.0. I uninstalled torchtext and then installed it with

> pip install torchtext==0.2.3.

And it worked for me. Let me know if you face any other problems.